# C# Windows universal list view binding buttons to icons fails

Tags: c#, windows, listview, uwp, win-universal-app

I have the following uwp listview

```
    <ListView x:Name="pane_listview"
          SelectionMode="Single"
         ItemsSource="{x:Bind paneDataItems}">

              <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:PaneItems">
                       <Grid>
                           ..column definations

                        <Button FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"  //icon display fails
                                    Content="{x:Bind icon}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    />
                                   ...other controls here

                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                </ListView>
```

This is the ItemDataSource

```
private List<PaneItems> paneDataItems;
 paneDataItems = PaneManager.GetPaneItems(); //called in the app initialization class
```

And now the getall items

```
public class PaneManager
{
    public static List<PaneItems> GetPaneItems()
    {
        var items = new List<PaneItems>();
        items.Add(new PaneItems("&#xE700;", "Dashboard", "can_view_dashboard"));
        return items;
    }
}

public class PaneItems
{
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string item { get; set; }
    public string permission { get; set; }

    public PaneItems(string iconval, string itemname, string permissionname)
    {
        icon = iconval;
        item = itemname;
        permission = permissionname;

    }

}
```

The problem is on the Button in the Listview It doesnt display the icon but when i set the icon in the listview manually as

```
<Button FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" /> //this works
```

As you can see the icon set in the PaneManager is the same as the icon set manually in the button;

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `&#xE700;` with `\uE700`.

So basically replace `&#x` with `\u` and remove the `;` in the end, whenever you want to reference the icon string in C# code-behind.